# Is it possible to have 2 views associated with one action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following custom route

```
routes.MapRoute("custom", "Groups/{groupname}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Groups", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

This custom route is to achieve the following url schema

- Groups/pokerclub/members/ - list all the members of pokerclub group.
- Groups/pokerclub/members/bob - list member details of bob.

I tried the following but it doesnt work. it confuses asp .net mvc of which action to select.

```
public ActionResult Members(string groupName, string id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Members(string groupName)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

There are two possible solutions that i could think of:

- Have different action name. e.g. Memberlist action and member action.
- Handle this in the view using simple if statement.

I very much want to maintain my url scheme. thus, as per my original question, how to have two different views associated to one action? Thanks.

RWendi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have one action, but you can perform whatever logic you want inside that action, and you can call views by name:

```
return View("MyView");
```

In your example, you would simply return a different view if the `id` field was null.

Answer (score 2):

where it says `return View();`   It takes parameters and you can get it to use whatever view you would like

```
return View("Members", model);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use different methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Members(string groupName, string id)
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Members(string groupName)
{
    return View();
}
```